# JS Howto define function on subobjects

Tags: javascript

I have an object containing nested objects, lets say:

```
var root = {
   'areas' : [
        {  'areaName' : 'A1',
           'modules' : [ { 'moduleName' : 'M1', moduleType : 'F' },
                         { 'moduleName' : 'M2', moduleType : 'F' }] },
        {  'areaName' : A2,
           'modules' : [ { 'moduleName' : 'M1', moduelType : 'B' },
                         { 'moduleName' : 'M2', moduleType : 'F' }] }
   ];        
}
```

This is a Json returned from a WS. I want to define a functions that can be called upon modules. Lets say:

```
root.A1.M2.Foo();
```

1) Can this be done in a fashionably way? I could iterate over all the objects in a for loop and add the function for each object. But I was looking more in the direction of using a prototype or something alike.

2) Can it be done to define this function so it has knowledge of its position in the hierarchy? So that you can do:

```
function Foo(){
     var module = ... ('this', I assume)
     var area = ...
     var root = ...
}
```

3) Bonus-question: Can it be archived to add the function only if a certain condition is met? So that Foo() is only added to modules with moduleType == 'F' and Bar() to modules with moduleType == 'B'

```
root.A1.M1.Foo(); // good
root.A2.M1.Bar(); // good
root.A2.M2.Bar(); // bad
```

I do have control about the WS, so returning the object in another format is possible, although not preferable.

Looking forward to your creative solutions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An attempt to get what you want. This goes straigth to point 3, returning a function with dependent name. the reurn value is the path, it could be all other reference to this object or another.

Your point 2 is a bit vague, where should

```
var module = ... ('this', I assume)
var area = ...
var root = ...
```

point to?

And another question arised, is the structure fixed? are the properties fixed? ans where should the result point to? To the original object or like this proposal to a different one?

```js
function iter(o, r, key, a) {
    key = key || 'root';
    a = a || [key];
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        if (~k.indexOf('Name')) {
            a = a.slice();
            r[key] = r[key] || {};
            r = r[key];
            key = o[k];
            a.push(o[k]);
            return;
        }
        if (~k.indexOf('Type')) {
            r[key] = {};
            r[key][{ F: 'Foo', B: 'Bar' }[o[k]]] = function () {
                return a;
            };
            return;
        }
        if (Array.isArray(o[k])) {
            o[k].forEach(function (b) {
                iter(b, r, key, a);
            });
            return;
        }
        if (typeof o[k] === 'object') {
            iter(o[k], r, key, a);
        }
    });
}

var object = { root: { areas: [{ areaName: 'A1', modules: [{ moduleName: 'M1', moduleType: 'F' }, { moduleName: 'M2', moduleType: 'F' }] }, { areaName: 'A2', modules: [{ moduleName: 'M1', moduleType: 'B' }, { moduleName: 'M2', moduleType: 'F' }] }] } },
    result = {};

iter(object, result);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write(result.root.A1.M1.Foo() + '<br>');
document.write(result.root.A1.M2.Foo() + '<br>');
document.write(result.root.A2.M1.Bar() + '<br>');
document.write(result.root.A2.M2.Foo() + '<br>');
```

Comment: I intended root to be the result, so adding an extra level wasn't needed. Also Foo() / Bar() where intended to have different implementations. But I can start with it and figure out the rest.

Answer (score 1):

A good result should be reached using `ECMASCRIPT-6 Proxies` as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

unfortunately, the current support of *es6 proxies* isn't good but almost all vendors are working to make it available as soon as possible. https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

this is a google polyfill: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/proxy-polyfill

Answer (score 0):

1) array.prototype.map() can help you. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map

```
var test = [{id : 1}, {id : 2}];
var newTest = test.map(function (i) {i.value = 'a'});
console.log(newTest);
// [{id : 1, value : 'a'}, {id : 2, value : 'a'}]
```

2 & 3) I don't understand, sorry, language limits

Answer (score 0):

You can think about the object you receive from sockets, like about raw data that must be deserialized [1]. So you can define a factory [2] that accepts this raw data and constructs objects with format and methods that you need. As a bonus this will help you decouple data representation from logic, so in future you can change format of data you sending via network with less effort.

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)